# Android Facebook SDK getting unexpected exception error

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I follwed facebook official guideline here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

but whenever I tried to share this error comes

> /com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger: Got unexpected exception:
>   java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception;
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was my Facebook app outdated. once I updated  the app. now it's all working